# How do I change the background theme in Lightning App Builder?

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I'm constructing a App Home Page using Lightning App Builder. How do I change the background theme back to the default one (the one without any image or any other color)[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the background image and blue color to a "neutral gray".

In **Setup, enter Themes and Branding** in the Quick Find box, then select **Themes and Branding**, and select **Hide**.

Comment: The option to hide is no longer there - Winter 20